# Deriving $KE=0.5mv^2$ from the relativity equation

Tags: binomial-theorem, special-relativity

From this article: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/releng.html#c6

It shows how to derive the classical formula for Kinetic energy from Relativistic Kinetic energy. I've started at the solution for probably more than an hour, however my maths isn't strong enough to jump from this line to the next one here:

$$
\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+ \frac{\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}}{2!}\frac{v^4}{c^4}+\cdots
$$
$$
KE = \frac{1}{2} m_0 v^2 + \frac{3}{8} m_0 \frac{v^4}{c^2} + \frac{5}{16}m_0 \frac{v^6}{c^4}+\cdots
$$

If someone could show this mathematically, the denominator become too hard to rearrange for me.
Thanks

Comment: Ehmmm, doesn't $a=1,\,x=-\frac{v^2}{c^2},\,n=-\frac12$ help?

Comment: Yes that is already the conditions substituted into the formula on the first line of my image https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ4xG.png  but i cant work out how to get to the proceeding line from there, as I have that majorly awkward denominator of: 1+(0.5v^2/c^2)+(3/8)(v^4/c^4).. etc which is hard to rearrange while leaving the LHS alone

Comment: $(-1/2)\cdot (-3/2)=3/4$; $(3/4)/2 = 3/8$. Does that help?

Comment: GUYS so sorry i was showing the wrong line, i have updated the image to show the correct 1 sorry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsSTC.png i meant this 1

Answer (score 1):

From the top line, we have
$$
KE = m_0 c^2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-1\right)
$$
Using the binomial expansion, as Alexey Burdin noted with $a=1, x =-v^2/c^2,$ and $n=-1/2$, we have
$$
\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+ \frac{\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-3}{2}}{2!}\frac{v^4}{c^4}+\cdots
$$
$$
\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2} -1= \frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+ \frac{3}{8}\frac{v^4}{c^4}+\frac{5}{16}\frac{v^6}{c^6}+\cdots
$$Multiply this through by $m_0c^2$:
$$
KE = m_0 c^2\left(\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{-1/2} -1\right)= m_0 c^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+ \frac{3}{8}\frac{v^4}{c^4}+\frac{5}{16}\frac{v^6}{c^6}+\cdots\right)
$$
$$
\approx \frac{1}{2} m_0 v^2,
$$for $v<<c$.

Comment: Thank you, For some reason I totally forgot that: x^-0.5 = 1/x^0.5 (guess im kind of rusty), but your answer made that abundantly clear! I thought I was having this crazy denominator that I had to deal with ><
Thanks again!
btw what program are you using to write the math equations?